# How to play some videos from Wowza Streaming Engine?

Tags: stream, streaming, video-streaming, wowza, wowza-transcoder

I can not play a video from Wowza. I have some videos as .mp4 extension. How can i play these videos onto a html web site?
I created some stream files and SMIL files. But I can not have URL to run these videos.
I need to URL format to play videos from Wowza Server.

How can I get the URL to play videos?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question.  But--assuming you have Wowza Streaming Engine installed--you can click on Applications in the header and access the default live and VOD applications.  From there, you'll see a link to Test Players, and you'll see what the protocol-specific URIs look like.

Comment: <video controls>
            <source src="http://192.168.1.59/applications/vod/_definst_/sharedobjects/istiklal.mp4/playlist.m3u8">
        </video>
I have made that as you said but not streaming. Is there a problem on my code?. can you regular my code ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using the HTML5 video tag element for Wowza Streaming Engine streaming URLs can be a bit limited depending on the browser and OS platform you are using. Check to make sure that your browser/platform supports this playback. The latest version of Wowza has the new HTML5 Wowza Player that is supported cross-platform (and is available to users with a valid key).

I also see that your HLS playback format looks to be incorrect. It should be:

```
 http://[wowza-ip-address]:[port-number]/[application-name]/[instance-name]/[stream-path]/playlist.m3u8
```

Your port-number by default is usually 1935, and can be set from the Virtual Host Setup page. For application name, the pre-installed app is called "vod", and the default instance is "_definst_" (which is optional, but is recommended to use if you are using sub-folders for your VOD content). The stream path is the path and name of your VOD file, and is usually prefixed by either "mp4:" or "flv:", depending on the kind of file. Try playing back the installed sample.mp4 file:

```
 http://192.168.1.59:1935/vod/_definst_/mp4:sample.mp4/playlist.m3u8
```